# Accessing property of dynamically created QStandardItems in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm having a problem determining whether or not the checkboxes that are dynamically created have been checked or unchecked by the user in a simple GUI I've created.

I've adapted the relevant code and pasted it below. Although it may be easy to just create and name 4 QStandardItems, I'm dealing with many lists containing many different items that change quite a lot, so it isn't really feasible to create them myself.

Any help finding out how to access these properties would be much appreciated.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class Splash(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # imagine this is a very long list...
        self.seasons = ['summer','autumn','winter','spring']

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        list = QListView()
        model = QStandardItemModel()
        list.setModel(model)

        printbtn = QPushButton('print values')
        printbtn.clicked.connect(self.print_action)

        for season in self.seasons:
            item = QStandardItem(season)
            item.setCheckable(True)
            model.appendRow(item)

        model.dataChanged.connect(lambda: self.print_action(item.text()))


        layout.addWidget(printbtn)
        layout.addWidget(list)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.show()

    def print_action(self, item):
        print('changed', item)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Splash()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In short - I can detect when an item has been checked using model.dataChanged and connecting that to a function, but it cannot differentiate between the seasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you keep a reference to the list (or the model), you can search for the items by their text, and then get their check-state:

```
def print_action(self):
    model = self.list.model()
    for text in 'summer', 'autumn', 'winter', 'spring':
        items = model.findItems(text)
        if items:
            checked = items[0].checkState() == Qt.Checked
            print('%s = %s' % (text, checked))
```

Comment: Brilliant, exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to get notified when the checkState of a item has been changed.

In my opinion, there are possible two ways.

First way, QModel will emit "dataChanged" to refresh the view, so you can connect the signal which means the checkState of a item might be changed.

```
model.dataChanged.connect(self.test)

def test(self):
    pass
```

Second way, use a timer to notify yourself and you check it by yourselves.

```
timer = QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(self.test)
timer.start(1000)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm having some difficulty understanding how, using your answer, I would be able to deduce each of the four QStandardItem's checkstate. Do you mind elaborating?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to print the checkState and seasons of the item?

Comment: Printing for the purpose of this question, but for what I'm writing I just need to know if the user has checked the box / what checkstate the box is in.

Comment: I do not know whether the item will emit some signal if it's checkState changed. You can try the signal of "emitDataChanged" to verify it. The second way is using a QTimer instance to check if the state has changed.

Comment: model.dataChanged.connect(self.test) is a start - but currently doesn't differentiate between items. Thanks though!